# Breaking C# references

Tags: c#, reference

I was wondering when and why references get broken in C#?

The following code example highlights this:

```
StringBuilder a = null, b = null;
a = new StringBuilder("a");
b = a;
b.Append("b");
b = null;
Console.WriteLine(a != null? a.ToString() : "null");
Console.WriteLine(b != null ? b.ToString() : "null");

//Output: 
    ab
    null
```

Why is it, for this example, that `b`'s reference to `a` does not cause `a` to be `null` as well?

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057267/difference-between-reference-type-and-value-type-in-c-sharp/5057284#5057284

Comment: Important to understand the difference between reference and value types in .NET programming.  Any decent book talks about it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to distinguish between *variables*, *references* and *objects*.

This line:

```
b = a;
```

sets the value of `b` to the value of `a`. That value is a reference. It's a reference to an *object*. At this point, making changes to that object *via* either `a` or `b` will just make changes to the same object - those changes would be visible via either `a` or `b` too, as both still have references to the same object.

They're like two pieces of paper with the same house address written on them though - the two variables don't know anything about each other, they just *happen* to have the same value due to the previous line.

So, when we change the value of `b` on this line:

```
b = null;
```

that *just* changes the value of `b`. It sets the value of `b` to a null reference. This makes no changes to either the value of `a` *or* the `StringBuilder` object which the old value of `b` referred to.

I have an [article which goes into more details on this](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/references.html), and which you may find useful.

Answer (score 11):

Variable `b` does not have a reference to variable `a`, it has a reference to the `StringBuilder` object referred to by `a`. That's what `b=a` does, it assigns to `b` a reference to the object referred to by `a`. As long as this is the case, any changes to the object via `b` are visible when the object is used via `a`.

When `b` gets assigned `null`, it no longer has a reference to any object, but `a` still maintains its reference.

Here is a picture depicting this:

[image: References]

Comment: Picture's worth 1000 words and all that =).

Answer (score 7):

You need to think separately about the *reference* and the *object*. There is one object, the `StringBuilder`. A reference is *essentially* the memory location of the object (give or take some notional abstraction), with a value of some large integer. You have two references variables.

```
StringBuilder a = null, b = null; // both variables empty
a = new StringBuilder("a"); // a ref to the obj, b empty
b = a; // copy value (ref) of a to b: a and b both ref to obj
b.Append("b"); // no change to either VARIABLE; the OBJECT has changed state
b = null; // clear the variable b; a still points to the obj
```

Also note that even if we add

```
a = null; // both variables empty
```

we still have 2 empty variables and one object; the object doesn't magically disappear - that is what garbage collection (GC) is for.

Comment: @IAbstract I reverted your edit; my code was right as written; the line in question *does not alter `b`*.

Answer (score 6):

b doesn't have a reference to a.  There is no "a" to refer to.  You have an **object** in memory (the stringbuilder) and two *different variables* that refer to it.  The line `b = a` makes a *copy* of the reference in a and assigns it to b.

Answer (score 2):

When you set `b = a;`, you are saying "`b` points to the object that `a` also points to in memory." So when you do this:

`b.Append("b");`

Doing this is the exact same thing:

`a.Append("b");`

But what it really is (for both `a` and `b`) is:

`[Object memory reference of a and b].Append("b");`

Comment: I don't think the last part of your answer is quite right and could be confusing, I would rephrase it say that `b.Append("b")` is the equivalent of `a.Append("b")` as both references point to the same object.